# What does "in" mean in "tie a knot in the rope"?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

What does "in" mean in "tie a knot in the rope"? Can "on" be substituted for "in"?

Comment: Google 5-grams for "tie a knot in/on/along the" do show that 'on' _is_ used in these strings, but far less frequently than 'in'. Also, examples usually have a prepositional complement like 'other end' / 'back of' / 'Sabbath' (!), so I'd avoid the choice of 'tie a knot on the rope.'. (note the standalone marker) // '...a knot in ...' is arguably a use of the container metaphor for linear features. Compare 'a link in the chain' / 'a kink in the cable'.

Comment: In relation to the criteria for up and down votes (hover over the voting arrows to see them), the question does not "show research effort", so someone has reasonably downvoted it; on the other hand it is "useful and clear" so I have upvoted it; the net result is one up one down. As a newcomer, please look at the help guide to see how to formulate good questions.

Answer (score 2):

One of many meanings of **in** is:

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in)
>
> in (Entry 1 of 11)
> used as a function word to indicate inclusion, location, or position within limits
> *in the lake*
> *wounded in the leg*
> *in the summer*

A knot *in* the rope is thus a knot within the limits of the rope (the ends). Topologically, the knot cannot be removed if the ends remain fixed. Here is an example in which the knot cannot be undone without manipulating the ends:

[image]

In contrast, **on** also has many meanings but the preposition often has the feeling of contact with, of removability and of adjacency:

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on)
>
> used as a function word to indicate position in contact with and supported by the top surface of something
> *the book is lying on the table*
>
> used as a function word to indicate position in or in contact with an outer surface
> *the fly landed on the ceiling*

A knot formed from a rope than can be **removed** without manipulating the ends  is topologically different from an "in" knot and might therefore be described as a knot *on* the rope. Here is an example of a knot that may be removed without end manipulation:

[image]

A knot "on" the rope

Comment: Nicely developed. But the distinction you mention isn't rigidly observed. I'd copy 'Tie an overhand knot in the rope for each person that is in the group (12 participants = 12 knots).... Space the knots about two feet apart....
Tell ... each person to select a knot on the rope and stand by it on either side of the rope....' [[Venture Team Building](https://ventureteambuilding.co.uk/rope-knots-game/#.YgPfrbrP3RY)]

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks for that and for the apt qualification. Although I find the topological argument useful it is also a bit recondite for all common usage.

Comment: Prepositions are the most bewilderingly metaphorical and polysemous words.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Agreed. They are the mantraps of translation!